# NDSolve and PDEs with integration

Tags: differential-equations

I am attempting to determine the steady-state solution, specifically the absolute maximum displacement over an extended time, which, from the physics of the problem, is known to be oscillatory in nature. The goal is to plot this displacement against the forcing frequency.

A challenge has arisen while using Mathematica's NDSolve to solve a PDE: despite no delay term being present, an error related to delay equations is being generated, with the PDE incorporating an integral term.

Insight or advice from those experienced with PDEs and integral terms would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your time and consideration.

Thanks for help in anticipation,

```
(*Parameters*)
 data = {n -> 1, \[Epsilon] -> 1, \[Alpha]1 -> 10., \[Alpha]2 -> 
10., \[Mu] -> .2, F[x_] -> 8, p -> 1};

 (*PDE*)
 pde = -\[Epsilon]^2 Cos[t \[Omega]] F[x] + \[Alpha]1 u[x, 
  t] + \[Alpha]2 \[Epsilon] u[x, t]^3 + 
2 \[Epsilon]^2 \[Mu] D[u[x, t], {t, 1}] + D[u[x, t], {t, 2}] - 
1/2 \[Epsilon] (Integrate[(D[u[z, t], {z, 1}])^2, {z, 0, 1}]) D[
  u[x, t], {x, 2}] + D[u[x, t], {x, 4}] == 0;

 (*Boundary and Initial Conditions*)
 bc = {u[0, t] == 0, u[1, t] == 0, D[u[x, t], {x, 2}] == 0 /. x -> 0, 
 D[u[x, t], {x, 2}] == 0 /. x -> 1, u[x, 0] == 0, 
 D[u[x, t], t] == 0 /. t -> 0};

  (*Specific Omega Value*)
   \[Omega]Value = 10; (*Example value*)

 (*Define T:the final time up to which you want to solve the PDE*)
 T = 100; (*Example value,adjust as needed*)

  (*Numerical Solution*)
  sol = NDSolve[{pde, bc} /. data /. \[Omega] -> \[Omega]Value, 
   u, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, T}];
```

Comment: From all you know about your problem, is there any chance that you could start with `U[x,t]` being the unknown function that is the result of the indefinite integration. Then your definite integral is `U[1,t]-U[0,t]` and you form a chain of derivatives of `U` all the way down. And you give `NDSolve` the equalities made up of those derivatives and see if it can give you `U`. Then you find derivatives of that to give you  the function you want. I'm thinking to "push" the order of the derivatives to get rid of the `Integrate` and still give you the solution you are looking for.

Comment: Thank @Bill for your comment. What I know is that the solution is oscillatory in nature.